# How to fix an argument count mismatch error in a child class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have three classes

**BaseShape**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.system.System;

    public class BaseShape extends MovieClip
    {
        var isActive:Boolean;
        public function BaseShape(iX:int, iY:int)
        {
            x = iX;
            y = iY;
            isActive=true;
        }
        //Other function here
    }
}
```

**Pentangular**

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Pentangular extends BaseShape {
        public function Pentangular(iX:int, iY:int) {
            super(iX, iY);
        }
    }

}
```

**PentangularClk**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class PentangularClk extends Pentangular {
        public function PentangularClk(iX:int, iY:int) {
            super(iX, iY);
            Cross.visible=false;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setActive);
        }
        private function setActive(e:MouseEvent):void{
            Tick.visible=!Tick.visible;
            Cross.visible=!Cross.visible;
            isActive=Tick.visible;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use in main (stage) class

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var myShape:Array=new Array();
        var toVertical:int=0;
        var toHorizontal:int=0;
        var pressedKeys:Object = { };
        public function Main()
        {
            SpeedShape.value=8;
            SpeedShape.minimum=0;
            SpeedShape.maximum=20;
            SpeedShape.stepSize= 1;
            RotationShape.value=8;
            RotationShape.minimum=1;
            RotationShape.maximum=20;
            RotationShape.stepSize= 1;
            myShape[0] = new Star(mainShape.width / 2,mainShape.height / 4);
//Next line makes this MovieClip
            myShape[1] = new PentangularClk(-1 * mainShape.width / 2,-1 * mainShape.height / 4);
            mainShape.addChild(myShape[0]);
            mainShape.addChild(myShape[1]);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,moveShapeByKeyboard);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,moveShapeByKeyboard,true);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,stopShapeByKeyboard);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,stopShapeByKeyboard,true);
        }
    }
}
```

### UPD: Added on 2016-05-13

There are two MovieClips on my library:

- Pentangular
- PentangularClk

The PentangularClk are based on Pentangular - it has all shapes from Pentangular.

---

My SWF is launched and works. But I see the next message:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Pentangular(). Expected 2, got 0.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at BaseShape()
    at Pentangular()
    at PentangularClk()
    at Main()
```

I checked what kind parameters are sent to classes. They are Ok. I don't understand the reason of this message.

Comment: Are you sure this line causes e the error? Please post more code from Main.

Comment: @Konstantin Try to verify if you haven't inserted manually any instance to the stage ...

Comment: The error you posted indicates you have an instance of `PentangularClk` placed on the main timeline somewhere. Timeline placed instances *cannot* be passed constructor arguments.

Comment: to fix make those argument optional.

Comment: There are not any `PentangularClk` MovieClips on the stage, I checked that many times. I placed the code of main class' constructor on my previous message.

@BotMaster Which classes in?

Comment: What is the point of `super(iX, iY);` in both **PentangularClk** & **Pentangular**? It almost makes sense when used in one of them but I can't see why it's in both classes. What does this achieve? I wonder if it's causing an issue maybe...

Comment: @VC.One
It's the call of the constructor of the parent class

Comment: Obviously someone calls constructor without arguments. Aaron's version is most probably. You could try this thing to prove it: Make default values of iX and iY like this for all 3 constructors this way: "public function PentangularClk(iX:int = 0, iY:int = 0)" just for test, and place breakpoints into constructors. Then run and you will see who calls constructor without arguments.

Comment: @Konstantin OK somehow I missed the point (edited?) that you have code in timeline MovieClips & assumed you were importing **.as** files as classes. Hence my confusion. Things like having function with arguments as `Pentangular(iX:int, iY:int)` whose only code is `super(iX, iY);` is likely not helping your program to work. Are you expecting to use  arguments `iX`and `iY` to set positions of `cross` & `tick`?

Comment: @VC.One You're a bit wrong. I have complex MovieClip which consists of the shapes (another MovieClips). And the parameters iX and iY are used to positioning all shapes as one.

Comment: @Konstantin, now do you understand all the question marks? We need clarification. Imagine if all that info was in your question, could have been solved yesterday. Glad its fixed for you now. I'll +1 for finding your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions.
The constructor `Pentangular` are called twice when `PentangularClk` is added and when its children shape (`Pentangular`) is added too.

In the second time, the constructor is called without any parameters.

So, the recommendation of @Selirion fits for me.
I just made default values of `iX` and `iY`.

Now it looks like

```
public function Pentangular(iX:int=0, iY:int=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `PentangularClk(iX:int, iY:int)` expects two variables of integer type, so try (untested) :

```
var int1 : int = (-1 * mainShape.width / 2);
var int2 : int = (-1 * mainShape.height / 4);

myShape[1] = new PentangularClk(int1, int2);
```

Alternatively you could try like this...

```
myShape[1] = new PentangularClk( int(-1 * mainShape.width / 2), int(-1 * mainShape.height / 4) );
```